# Insert Excel Data Into Access, But Cell Contains No Data?

Tags: vb.net, excel, ms-access, insert, epplus

I am iterating through some rows/cells in an Excel sheet and some of the cells are blank. When I try to do the insert, if a cell contains no data, it advises me that that particular parameter has no default value. In Access, I have set the default value to "=Null" but I still receive the error. Do I have to do an If statement as shown below for every parameter in order to prevent errors? I'd like to clean up my code if possible.

```
If worksheet1.GetValue(i, 14) Is Nothing Then
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param1", OleDbType.Char).Value = DBNull.Value
                        Else
                            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param1", OleDbType.Char).Value = worksheet1.GetValue(i, 14)
                        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience (albeit C#), yes you do. Interop (which is what I'm assuming you're using although I don't recognise the `GetValue()` call) usually throws an exception when you try to get data from an empty cell without first checking. The way I've handled it is to wrap the code in a method and just call it each time (sorry, my VB is a little rusty):

```
Public Function GetCellContents(column As Integer, row As Integer) As String

    If worksheet1.GetValue(column, row) Is Nothing Then
        Return ""
    Else
        Return worksheet1.GetValue(column, row)
    End If

End Function
```

And then you can just do:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Param1", OleDbType.Char).Value = GetCellContents(i, 14);
```

Comment: I'm using EPPlus. I'm going to go with your suggestion since it's an excellent idea. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user1066133 Aha, that's why I didn't recognise the method. I should have a go with EPPlus, it looks quite good. Glad I could help.